# Android Studio Robolectric missing android.R

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a very hard time solving this problem in Android studio.

I have made an app, and trying to test it with this Robolectric test tool, but it seems like robolectric cant find android jar files although android jar is running perfectly when i run the app by it self. My friend has a clone of the test and the app at his computer, and here i runs perfectly. What i wrong ?

Please help me out here.

This is the failure:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/R
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.Setup.(Setup.java:39)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSetup(RobolectricTestRunner.java:137)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.createSdkEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:114)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$3.create(RobolectricTestRunner.java:307)
    at org.robolectric.EnvHolder.getSdkEnvironment(EnvHolder.java:21)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.getEnvironment(RobolectricTestRunner.java:305)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.access$300(RobolectricTestRunner.java:61)

And this is the app gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'robolectric'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 18
        buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kea.project.wheeloffortune"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 18

        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            setRoot('src/test')
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
        classpath 'org.robolectric:robolectric-gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/espresso-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/testrunner-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('lib/espresso-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('lib/testrunner-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile files('lib/testrunner-runtime-1.1.jar')
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.1'
    androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.1'
    androidTestCompile('junit:junit:4.11') {
        exclude module: 'hamcrest-core'
    }
    androidTestCompile('org.robolectric:robolectric:2.3') {
        exclude module: 'classworlds'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact'
        exclude module: 'maven-artifact-manager'
        exclude module: 'maven-error-diagnostics'
        exclude module: 'maven-model'
        exclude module: 'maven-project'
        exclude module: 'maven-settings'
        exclude module: 'plexus-container-default'
        exclude module: 'plexus-interpolation'
        exclude module: 'plexus-utils'
        exclude module: 'wagon-file'
        exclude module: 'wagon-http-lightweight'
        exclude module: 'wagon-provider-api'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.+'
}

idea {
    module {
        testOutputDir = file('build/test-classes/debug')
    }
}

task addTest {
    def src = ['src/test/java']
    def file = file("app.iml")

    doLast {
        try {
            def parsedXml = (new XmlParser()).parse(file)
            def node = parsedXml.component[1].content[0]
            src.each {
                def path = 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}"
                def set = node.find { it.@url == path }
                if (set == null) {
                    new Node(node, 'sourceFolder', ['url': 'file://$MODULE_DIR$/' + "${it}", 'isTestSource': "true"])
                    def writer = new StringWriter()
                    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(parsedXml)
                    file.text = writer.toString()
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // nop, iml not found
        }
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    preBuild.dependsOn(addTest)
}

robolectric {
    include '**/*Test.class'
    exclude '**/espresso/**/*.class'
}
```